# Difference between BAM mediator and Mediation Statistics

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Why there are two different data agents, BAM mediator and Mediation Statistics available for ESB? What are the differences and similarities in each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediation Statistics data agent is used to send accumulated statistics of mediation in ESB to the BAM. It sends events to BAM periodically.

But BAM mediator is different. It can be defined any location as a mediator in a mediation sequence of ESB. Even multiple times. Each BAM mediator can independently send events to the BAM side via the defined stream. And also BAM mediator sends events each time a message is passed through the BAM mediator.